# How can I say "looking through the window of death"?

Tags: translation

How can I talk about death's point of view?

Comment: 死の窓から見ること  but i don't think it is a proper translate =)

Comment: What does that expression exactly mean? I suppose you do not mean "the blue/red screen of death" of Microsoft Windows OS.

Comment: @sawa It sounds like an artistic way of saying either: "looking at life through the lens of death" or "looking through to _the other side_".

Comment: @summea To me, that does not make much difference from the original expression. You just changed "window" to "lens". It is still too abstract.

Comment: @sawa How sad language would be if it were limited to linguistic thinking.

Comment: @summea I don't understand the intention of you comment at all. Why are you suddenly mentioning "linguistic thinking"? How is that relevant? I don't understand how "looking through the lens of death" can be an explanation to "looking through the window of death".

Comment: @sawa In English, lens and window can be similar.  They are both things through which something can be viewed.  My comment earlier is basically this: abstract ideas do not necessarily have to follow form.

Comment: Sorry for asking a basic question but, what does exactly 'window of death' mean? Is it some kind of metaphor?

Comment: @Chocolate I'm not sure myself, but maybe it means you're on one side of the window ("living") and looking at what's outside/inside ("death" or "the afterlife") through it. In other words "looking from death's perspective"? 日本語だと、「死の観点から見ること」、それとも「冥界の観点から見ること」ではないでしょうか？？？　いまいち分からないのですが…

Comment: Please provide more context so we can determine how "window of death" is used. Perhaps provide a couple of sentences preceding and succeeding the phrase?

Comment: I agree with Flaw. You should edit your question with examples in English and the attempted Japanese.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean "from the perspective of the afterworld", which I inferred from the comments, then a corresponding expression may be:

> 三途の川の向こう側から
>   'from the other side of the [sanzu river](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanzu_River)'

Answer (score 3):

How about 「死の世界から」 or 「死後の世界から」?? (--Hmm maybe not.)

Answer (score 2):

What about something like:

> 死の窓から眺めること.

Or even:

> 死の窓から眺める 風景{ふうけい}.